# How to generate setters which return Object(self) in Android Studio or Intellij-Idea

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Im looking to easy way to set many parameters to object and return object itself. So I can set any object. something like:

```
public class Foo {

    private int mValue1;
    private String mValue2;
    private boolean mValue3;
    private long mValue4;

    public Foo() {
    }

    public Foo setValue1(int value1) {
        mValue1 = value1;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo setValue2(String value2) {
        mValue2 = value2;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo setValue3(boolean value3) {
        mValue3 = value3;
        return this;
    }

    public Foo setValue4(long value4) {
        mValue4 = value4;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I am looking for an auto-generate tool which helps me to achieve that.

Having them(members) in constructor enforcing me to set null for all members. Also having over-loading constructors are headache when update members.

Comment: Why are you returning a value from a method named `setXxx()`?

Comment: You are returning the instance of class. that might be helpful in build design . i.e. new object1().seXxx(101).setYyy(202).setZzz(303).build() ..in one line you have initialization and optional setters and build method.

Comment: OIC. You are creating a Builder. Makes sense now. (And I assume you mean `new object1().....`, right?)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think I found the answer .. There is a shipped template called `Builder` with Android Studio (Intellij-Idea) does that job smoothly.

1. Press when you want to generate setters inside class
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> on OSX or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> on Windows/Linux ( credit to [Shashanth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641479/how-to-generate-setters-which-return-objectself-in-android-studio-or-intellij/41641586#comment70525134_41641586) ).
   You can also run generate via menu Code => Generate
3. Click on Setters
4. Switch to `Builder` template from Template menu
5. Select members to be generated
6. OK

Even more you can customise the setter template

Good luck,'.

[image: generate setter which returns self (this)]

Comment: For Windows and Linux users use `Alt` + `Insert` to generate Constructors, Getters or Setters. And thank you for the awesome answer I didn't know it. +1